# How to use methods of classes in libaries?

Tags: python, methods, scipy

I am currently trying to figure out how to use methods in imported libaries. For example we can take the *scipy.inerpolate.interp2d* function:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html

```
from scipy import interpolate
x = np.arange(-5.01, 5.01, 0.25)
y = np.arange(-5.01, 5.01, 0.25)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = np.sin(xx**2+yy**2)
f = interpolate.interp2d(x, y, z, kind='cubic')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xnew = np.arange(-5.01, 5.01, 1e-2)
ynew = np.arange(-5.01, 5.01, 1e-2)
znew = f(xnew, ynew)
plt.plot(x, z[0, :], 'ro-', xnew, znew[0, :], 'b-')
plt.show()
```

At the bottom of the page there are listed all methods of this function. Now I am wondering, how do I use this method?

`scipy.interpolate.inerp2d(x, y, z, kind="cubic").__call__` didn't work.

Furthermore I would like to understand the difference between why there is a need to add methods to functions when someone could just use the function input?

Comment: `interp2d` is a *class*, not a function.  The class implements a `__call__()` method, which allows its instances to be called like a function; you invoke that ability via normal function calling syntax (`f(xnew, ynew)` in your example), rather than anything involving the name `__call__`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `__call__()` method is what's known as a dunder method, or a special method. It is what enables you to do things like `f()`. Since everything in python is an object, a `callable` is simply an object or instance that supports the call syntax `f()`. In this case, the `scipy` function you are importing and using returns a function.

The example you pasted has you using the function properly.

Comment: Thank you. this already shared some light on my intended question. Some other classes (for instance in numpy or scipy) contain multiple dunder methods. This class has multiple dunder methods for example, but it looks like something differenct for the lack of the "__". https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html#scipy.spatial.cKDTree. So these dunder methods ("__...__") are not intended to be used directly by dot notation or something similar, rather describe a property of the class? What is the difference to methods without the underscores?

Comment: There really isn't much of a difference. When you call `a.method()` or `a.__call__()`, the same chain of lookup occurs. The difference is that the `__call__()` method has special sauce that enables the syntax `a()`. When you call `a()`, what happens under the hood is `a.__call__()`. The same can be said for other dunder methods like `__eq__` and `__hash__`. Implementing these methods on your custom classes is similar to operator overriding in C++. For instance, implementing `__lt__` for a class will override the `less than` operator, changing the behavior of `a > b`